# Async Await in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```
console.log(1)
console.log(2)
console.log(3)
console.log(4)
console.log(5)

async function getUsers(){
  let res = await  fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  let finalRes = await res.json()

  console.log(finalRes)
}
getUsers()


console.log(6)
console.log(7)
```

*In the above code i am trying to execute getUsers() function between console.log(5) and console.log(6), however in the output i am getting the output of getUsers func after console.log(7) . Is there anything i am doing wrong or what needs to be done if i want the getUsers o/p between console.log 5 & 6*

Comment: You are not awaiting the result of `getUsers`

Comment: You need to await getUsers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the `getUsers()` function to finish. Currently you call it as if it were a plain function.

To do that, assuming the surrounding code is in a non-`async` context, you need to wrap the code in an `async` function:

```
async function getUsers(){
  let res = await  fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  let finalRes = await res.json()

  console.log(finalRes)
}
(async () => {await getUsers(); console.log(6);})();
```